# Im Trying To Make A Function But I Keep Getting "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str"

Tags: python

im making a text rpg game and this line of code

```
def choose():
    afterbattlechoice = int(input("Stats: Level:" + lvl + "Xp:" + xp + "HP" + hp + "What Do You Want To Do? | 1. Open Shop | 2. Adventure On :"))
    
    if afterbattlechoice == 1:
        print("You Venture To Alfies Golden Goods!")
```

keeps giving me this error message.
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

not sure whats wrong

ive tried changing it to a float and a regular input, neither works

i just need it to output the print.

Comment: Looks like `lvl`, `xp`, or `hp` is an int. Try wrapping them with `str()` like `str(lvl)`

Comment: Tip: use formatting! `f"{lvl}"` as an [f string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html). Concatenation just makes a mess of things, especially when it comes to conversion.

Comment: Repeated concatenation may also be a quadratic operation (though CPython does include an optimization to allow strings with no external references to be updated in place).

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the [tadman's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman) tip here, this would be the minimum working example:

```py
lvl = 1
xp = 2
hp = 3


def choose():
    afterbattlechoice = int(input(f"Stats: Level:{lvl}, Xp: {xp}, HP: {hp}. \n "
                                  f"What do you want to do? | 1. Open Shop | 2. Adventure Carries on"))
    if afterbattlechoice == 1:
        print("You Venture To Alfies Golden Goods!")


choose()
```

In general this is happening because in python you cannot add strings and numbers together, so `"a" + 3` would give you an `TypeError`.